# How to set custom aspect ratio in grid view in Android?

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am trying to set a 3:2 ratio for a gridview (IE 300 pixels by 200 per cell). Here is my image adapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3,
    };
}
```

I've tried adjusting the `imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));` width parameter to `300` but it results in overlapping. Here is my XML File:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

Weird overlapping: 
[image]

Comment: kindly response, did my answer help ?

Comment: It didn't work no, sorry saw the library before responding.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there you can try like this from your Activity :

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = gridview.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.height = 200;
layoutParams.width = 300;
gridview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

or

```
int final width = 300;
int final height = 200;
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lauoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width,height);
gridView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

This might help.

Comment: Within ImageAdapter activity?

Comment: no from main activity where you are calling adapter. where you have initialized gridView and other views inside onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

Discovered this library: [AsymetricGridView](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView)